# Where is my folder copied when I scp from a server to a name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp

So I wanted to copy a folder from a remote server to my local computer. I am using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)/ Ubuntu.

First, I ssh into the server using `ssh user@host`.
Then I wrote the scp command which is `scp -r user@host:/var/www backup-9-feb`

But now I cant find this backup-9-feb folder, please help. Unfortunately, I forgot the name of the folder too. This is just an example.

After I executed these commands, A long list of files with there paths were shown

Comment: The find command will be of use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to ssh into the server to use scp. You want to do the following on your computer: `scp -r server_user@server_host:/var/www backup-9-feb`. This will copy (recursively) the directory `/var/www` of the server to the **directory where you ran this command** on your machine.

Note: `scp` is going to be deprecated so you probably want to start using an utility like rsync (works similarly).

Comment: Can you point me to any tutorial for rsync, thanks. And I assume the folder wasn't copied then because I cant find it

Comment: I first heard of rsync from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTnWIKHtOnA . This web page also has great information: https://fedoramagazine.org/scp-users-migration-guide-to-rsync/